# How do i programmatically add multiple appointment tasks to a user's calendar in Windows Phone SilverLight 8.1

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I know how to add a single appointment task using SaveAppointmentTask, but what i want is to be able to create a schedule in my app (several appointments) and have the user sync with their calendar in one loop, instead of having to save all the appointments individually. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks